# react-native aws amplify (V6) Custom authentication challenge (passwordless)

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, amplify-auth-cognito

I have developed a app with react-native and Amplify(This is myApp1). And I implemented passwordless authentication using AWS Amplify. (Not exactly same but similar with https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/)

Now, I am creating a new app(This is myApp2) with react-native and exist amplify backend(using previous one).

When I was developing myApp1, Amplify library was V5, but now it's V6. So, myApp1 is developed by V5 and myApp2 is developed by V6.

belows are my code.

> myApp1 (V5)

```
const onSignInPressed = async data => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const username = data.username;
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signIn('+91' + username);
      setSession(user);
      setReady(true);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onVerifyOtp = async data => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const user = await Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(session, data.otp);
      setAuthUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

When the Sign In button is clicked, an OTP is sent, and upon entering the OTP, clicking the Verify OTP button uses sendCustomChallengeAnswer for login.

I modified my code as below by referring to AWS Documentation. (V6)
(https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/auth/switch-auth/#pageMain)

It says 'To initiate a custom authentication flow in your app, call signIn without a password. A custom challenge needs to be answered using the confirmSignIn'

> myApp2 (V6)

```
const onSignInPressed = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const user = await signIn({
        username: '+91' + phoneNumber,
        options: {
          authFlowType: 'CUSTOM_WITHOUT_SRP',
        },
      });

      setSession(user);
      setReady(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

const onVerifyOtp = async (otp) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      console.log(otp);
      console.log(session.nextStep.signInStep);
      const output = await confirmSignIn({otp});
      console.log(output);

      setDbUser(output);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('onVerifyOtp', err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

But I got below error.

```
 LOG  111111
 LOG  CONFIRM_SIGN_IN_WITH_CUSTOM_CHALLENGE
 ERROR  onVerifyOtp [EmptyChallengeResponse: challengeResponse is required to confirmSignIn]
```

If anyone has solutions, I'd greatly appreciate detailed explanations. (I am very new, I would really appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the parameter name, it works well if you transfer it to the confirmSignIn function as challengeResponse as shown below.

```
const challengeResponse = otp;
const user = await confirmSignIn({challengeResponse});
```